Unlocking and mounting Linux SSD disk
I have an encrypted SSD drive. It was encrypted during the installation of Ubuntu 22.04. Today the operating system failed to boot the disk and the system rebooted over and over right after loading the BIOS.
I decided to remove this disk and insert it into another computer with Ubuntu 22.04 installed, but the disk is only visible in the "Disks" application:

I don't see it in other locations:

However, there are two partitions visible in the Ubuntu toolbar:


After plugin the drive, pop-up password request with does not appear. So how can I boot the SSD so that I can enter the password and access its contents?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have edited the question I hope now this is more precise.

It might be easier to leave the drive in the PC, and to recover data, if possible, by booting from USB (e.g., Live Ubuntu). so there is no hardware change. Assuming it's LUKS encryption, see https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/how-to-recover-a-luks-encrypted-disk/. Of course, safest is to recover from the last disk image.

Booting from USB worked in this situation. I plugged only the encrypted SSD drive by USB and it start normally. I passed pasword and was eable to loging to the system! I already backup my data. Thank you so much for helping me!
